# How to do this in Django Admin. Control position with arrows

Tags: django, django-admin

I use a field called "website_position" to control the position of the url. This is an Integer field.

The model I use is this:
    from django.db import models
    import datetime

```
class Directory(models.Model):
 website_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 website_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 website_position = models.IntegerField()
 pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Now I will populate the database with data:

```
website_name | website_url                    | website_position | pub_date
Google       | http://www.google.com          | 1                | 10-08-2011
Yahoo        | http://www.yahoo.com           | 2                | 10-08-2011
Altavista    | http://www.altavista.com       | 3                | 10-08-2011
```

The output of this will be: Google, Yahoo, Altavista

Another example: (Here I will reorder the links positions)

```
website_name | website_url                    | website_position | pub_date
Google       | http://www.google.com          | 3                | 10-08-2011
Yahoo        | http://www.yahoo.com           | 2                | 10-08-2011
Altavista    | http://www.altavista.com       | 1                | 10-08-2011
```

Ant the output will be: Altavista, Yahoo, Google

The thing here is that I control the positions of the links in Django
Admin with integers in the field "website_position". I'd like to know
if Django Admin have a better way to deal with this. There is possible
to control this with arrows to change the position of links, I click
in the up arrow and the link go up... I click in a down arrow and the
link goes down... This is possible in the Django Admin?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about drag-and-drop?

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2057/

Answer (score 0):

I do basically the same thing in a view, not in the admin. Except I have to deal with subgroups and varying depths as well. My method is not fancy, there is no ajax or javascript or anything asynchronous. Basically I wrote functions and then call them from links to GET parameters.
It's quite crude, but seems to work very consistently.

```
def someview(request):
    directory_query = Directory.objects.all().order_by('website_position') 
    #or whatever you need to query here, order_by is important

    if 'f' in request.GET and 'id' in request.GET:
        function = request.GET['f']
        target_id = request.GET['id']
        order_functions(request, function, target_id, directory_query)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/current_url/') #using a target instead of "" clears GET
    return render_to_response('template.html', locals, context_instance=RequestContext(request),)

def order_functions(request, function, target_id, directory_query):
    target_obj = directory_query.get(id=target_id)
    target_index = directory_query.index(target_obj)
    max_position = len(directory_query)
    min_position = 1

    if target_index < (max_position - 1): #indexes start at 0, so have to subtract 1 from len
        obj_above = directory_query[target_index + 1]
    else:
        obj_above = None

    if target_index > 0:
        obj_below = directory_query[target_index - 1]
    else:
        obj_below = None

    if function == 'order_inc':
        if target_obj.website_position < max_position:
            target_obj.website_position += 1
            obj_above.website_position += -1
            target_obj.save()
            obj_above.save()

    if function == 'order_dec':
        if target_obj.website_position > min_position:
            target_obj.website_position += -1
            obj_below.website_position += 1
            target_obj.save()
            obj_below.save()

    return

#your template:
{% for item in directory_query %}
    <li>{{ item.website_position }}
        <input onclick="window.location.href='?f=order_dec&amp;id={{ item.id }}'" type='button' value='increase' />
        <input onclick="window.location.href='?f=order_inc&amp;id={{ item.id }}'" type='button' value='decrease' /> 
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm sure there are cleaner ways of doing it, and you'd still need to figure out how to add that to the admin.